# Is it not possible to mutate object returned from mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, json, mongoose

I'm using nodeJS and mongoose. I want to add new keys to existing object returned by mongoose query.

```
Poll.findById(eid)
        .then(poll => {
            poll['newField']=['value1', 'value2'];
            res.send(poll);
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

This code shows the previous values of poll with no new fields. But when I res.send(poll["newField"]) I can see ["value1","value2"] as output. How do I make res.send(poll) display object with newField ?

Comment: have you tried `Poll.findById(eid).lean().then(...)`

Comment: That works. Solved !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding .lean() as Poll.findById(eid).lean().then(...) solved it.